# Primefaces keyFilter regular expression number with decimal 0 or 5

Tags: regex, primefaces, keyfilter

I would like to use pe:keyFilter so that a user can enter a number
with the decimal parts only  containing 0 or 5. 
So, for example 6,5 or 7,0 are accepted but 6,3 is not accepted.

I have tried this

```
 <p:inputMask  id="time" value="#{cons.time}" styleClass="ore" mask="9,9" >
        <pe:keyFilter regEx="/([0-9]),(0|5)/g"/>
 </p:inputMask>
```

but the filter is not working.

Could you tell me what's wrong?

**EDIT**:

With wrong I mean that I could input for example a value like 6,2 . 
I saw someone suggesting using keyFilter with inputMask so that is why I used it. In response to #sheltem ,
I had already tried with inputText. It doesn't allow me to input anything at all. I cannot even paste  a value like 6,5 , which should be valid. 
Maybe I don't understand how keyFilter works or maybe it only works for simple 
regex. Anyway, in the end I solved with Javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"? Does it have no effect? If so, are you sure that you can use a keyFilter on an inputMask? Since the keyFilter will handle restricting the input, switching to inputText (a component that keyFilter is definitely defined for) may be helpful.

Comment: what the version that you use for primefaces and primefaces extensions ?
I noticed that maybe the issue in keyFilter itself : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/keyFilter.jsf here you can't type anything too.

Comment: I am using primefaces 5.2  and ext. 3.1

Comment: There are many issues in showcase for PE , as example see the ajax handlers and another components, did you try downgrade PE to 3.0 ?

Comment: actually I upgraded because there were issues with 3.0:)

Comment: Is this issue was one of the issues in 3.0? I just was want to "try" and troubleshoot issue, not telling you that the solution is downgrade.

Comment: This issue wasn't with 3.0. But with 3.0  I had a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error  that disappeared with 3.1